# Presets missing on a Aficio mp c6501

Tags: printing

At the printer company instructions installed new driver.  Now the preset gives no option for single page with staple.  It requires several clicks to the "finishing" to set for stapling.

Anybody else having this problem and is there a fix?  Only preset options is "basic (with no staple), 2 sided, 2 sided with staple, and landscape.  Occasionally there appears and "unregistered" option.  Is it possible to change the default on the unregistered option?

Answer (score 1):

Chances are very small that you encounter anyone with the same printer here, so I'll give a generic advice: try looking in the directory `/etc/cups/ppd/`. Most likely you will find a ppd file which corresponds to your printer. Different outputmodes may be defined in that file, and you could (after saving a backup copy of the original file) try to add a line which does what you want if the syntax of the other modes is clear.